# SQL: current timestamp + 1 hour when inserting into DB

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I've looked around and have only seen this being used when using SELECT, not INSERT and it has gotten me quite confused.

What I've been trying is:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO shipments (crate_type_id, username, arrival, quantity, type, status) VALUES ('$crate_type_id', '$username', 'DATE_ADD(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 HOUR)', '$quantity', 'purchase', 'active')");
```

I don't get any errors, it only inserts `"0000-00-00 00:00:00"`. I've tried troubleshooting in phpmyadmin etc but haven't made any progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the quotes arount the date_add expression and use comma not +

```
statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO shipments 
  (crate_type_id, username, arrival, quantity, type, status) 
  VALUES ('$crate_type_id', '$username',
         DATE_ADD(NOW() ,  INTERVAL 1 HOUR) ,
           '$quantity', 'purchase', 'active')");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're using `PDO::prepare()` incorrectly. The whole purpose of the tool is to separate code and data but you're injecting the latter into the former as if prepared statements had not been invented yet. You have several examples in the manual so I won't repeat that here but in short you have to:

1. Insert placeholders in your SQL code (`?` or `:foo`)
2. Provide actual values on execution

Secondly, I suggest you configure MySQL in strict mode so you don't end up with junk like `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. You can set a proper SQL mode on connection, e.g.:

```
SET @@SESSION.sql_mode='TRADITIONAL'
```

Finally, your final SQL code is possibly not even valid, but apparently you aren't being notified about it. I recommend you add something like this to your connection code:

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);
```

... and ensure you've configured your PHP development box to display all errors.

Comment: Thank you for this, I will definitely keep this in mind an give that last connection setup a try.